# Angular 4 switch with different components

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to make my menu load according to the click on the "Cadastros" action but I believe the problem is the "workspaceSelected" property that is not visible to all components.

I believe the correct location for this case would be the property "workspaceSelected" being in the component sidenav, but I do not know how to handle this type of situation.

I would like to click on the action "Cadastros" and she make the switch to load the correct html component.

principal component class:

```
export class PrincipalComponent implements OnInit {

  workspaceSelecionada: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Principal component:

```
<header>
    <app-navbar></app-navbar>
    <app-sidenav></app-sidenav>
</header>
<div class="container" [ngSwitch]="workspaceSelecionada">
    <app-cadastros *ngSwitchCase="'cadastros'"></app-cadastros>
    <app-movimentacoes *ngSwitchCase="'movimentacoes'"></app-movimentacoes>
    <app-administracao *ngSwitchCase="'administracao'"></app-administracao>
    <app-relatorios *ngSwitchCase="'relatorios'"></app-relatorios>
    <app-configuracoes *ngSwitchCase="'configuracoes'"></app-configuracoes>
    <app-dashboard *ngSwitchDefault></app-dashboard>
</div>
```

app-sidenav:

```
<!--SideNav-->
<ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav grey darken-2">
  <li>
    <div class="userView">
      <div class="background">
        <img src="images/office.jpg">
      </div>
      <a href="#!user"><img class="circle" src="images/yuna.jpg"></a>
      <a href="#!name"><span class="white-text name">John Doe</span></a>
      <a href="#!email"><span class="white-text email">jdandturk@gmail.com</span></a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a (click)="workspaceSelecionada = 'cadastros'" class="btn-large waves-effect waves-light indigo darken-3">CADASTROS</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="btn-large waves-effect waves-light purple darken-3">MOVIMENTAÇÕES</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="btn-large waves-effect waves-light orange darken-3">ADMINISTRAÇÃO</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="btn-large waves-effect waves-light yellow darken-3">RELATÓRIOS</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="btn-large waves-effect waves-light light-green darken-3">CONFIGURAÇÕES</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<a data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good use for `ngSwitch`. Take a look at the Angular `Router` instead.

Comment: @joh04667 Can you put some example of an answer? Because I am a beginner, so a hint of good practice can be considered an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested above in the comment, define a routing module for the application:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import {CadastrosComponent} from './...component';
....

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'cadastros', component: CadastrosComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {

}
```

Then import the routing module in your app module:

`imports: [AppRoutingModule]`

Then instead of switch case statement in your principal component, define the router outlet as below:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Then in the anchor tag in your side nav component template, define the router link as below:

```
<a routerLink="/cadastros">CADASTROS</a>
```

Hope this helps! Do let me know if you face any challenges implementing it.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Thanks for your help! I am new to CSS, your code really helped me.

Comment: I am facing the same situation where I cannot use router-outlet because I already have one. Can I do This in any other way